# How to authorize asana api using requests library?

Tags: python-requests, asana, asana-api

I have following details : asana personal access token, asana client-id, asana client secret. I have installed [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). I dont know how to use these details and access my asana user details, projects etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide more detail and clarity around what you are trying to accomplish accompanied by code snippets where relevant I may be able to help more specifically.

Generally, however, you will not need a [Personal Access Token](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth#personal-access-token) and your [OAuth App credentials](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth#oauth) in the same application. They are mostly mutually exclusive.

The Personal Access Token is good for a personal app that only you will use and OAuth well suited for an app which will support many users authenticating on.

When writing applications against the Asana API in Node JS you should consider using the [official Node JS client library](https://github.com/Asana/node-asana) for simple & easy support of the API.

Comment: i am unable to find the exact line to write for authorization using requests.